# Removing diacritics in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

The problem is trivial, taking a string in some language remove the diacritics symbols. For example taking "téléphone" produces the result "telephone".

In Java I can use such method:

```
 public static String removeAccents(String str){
    return Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

and it works fine but in scala it doesn't... I tried the code as follows:

```
val str = Normalizer.normalize("téléphone",Normalizer.Form.NFD)
val exp = "\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+".r
exp.replaceAllIn(str,"")
```

it does't work!

I think, I'm missing something in using Regex in Scala, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both seem to work fine for me. Just guessing from your code, maybe you're expecting that `replaceAllIn` will modify your `str` in place. That's not going to happen, because strings in Java/Scala are immutable.

Comment: @ghik No, I'm not expecting so, but the result I got with scala is :

Comment: I expect that it returns new string without the diacritics symbols, but it returns exactly the same string - with "téléphone" it gives "téléphone"... @ghik How it works for you?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ghik/90abb2df635fb792c5ff

Comment: @ghik Initialy I was testing this code on Win8 platform and it doesn't work. Now I have tried it on Ubuntu and it works fine, what is the reason?

Comment: @arussinov: Check source file encoding in both OS. In Ubuntu it will be `utf8`, in Win8 - ?.

Comment: @senia source file encoding in win8 utf-8 and us_ascii in Ubuntu, in addition runing this code in terminal in Win8 gives no result, in ubuntu terminal it works.

Comment: The REPL uses jline for line editing, maybe jline config is your problem if you've only tried the code in the REPL. It worked for me on cygwin REPL and eclipse when I was briefly booted into win7. Latest 2.11 uses jline 2, maybe worth a shot, just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue using Normalizer. Found a solution from [Apache Commons StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) in the form of stripAccents, which removes diacitics from a String.

```
 val str = stripAccents("téléphone")
 println(str)
```

This will yield "telephone". Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, create a function to return the value of `stripAccents`.

```
val spark=SparkBase.getSparkSession()

val sc=spark.sparkContext
import spark.implicits._

val str = stripAccents("téléphone")
println(str)

val str2 = stripAccents("SERNAQUE ARGÜELLO NORMA ELIZABETH")
println(str2)

case class Fruits(name: String, quantity: Int)
val sourceDS = Seq(("YÁBAR ARRIETA JENSON", 1), ("SERNAQUE ARGÜELLO NORMA ELIZABETH", 2)).toDF("text","num")

val check = udf((colValue: String) => {
  stripAccents(colValue)
})

sourceDS.select(col("text"),check(col("text"))).show(false)
```

->OUTPUT

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|text                             |UDF(text)                        |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|YÁBAR ARRIETA JENSON             |YABAR ARRIETA JENSON             |
|SERNAQUE ARGÜELLO NORMA ELIZABETH|SERNAQUE ARGUELLO NORMA ELIZABETH|
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```